# delete all rows from first 3 columns of a worksheet (keeping the row with column names) using openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl

I am relatively new to Python. I am unable to figure out how to delete all rows (without deleting the row with column names) of specific columns with openpyxl.

I have tried the below code but it is deleting all rows of all columns in the sheet.

```
wb = xl.load_workbook('test.xlsx')
ws = wb['Sheet1']

for row in ws.iter_rows(min_row=1, max_row=sheet.max_row, min_col=1, max_col=3):
       ws.delete_rows(row[1].row, ws.max_row - 1)
```

Comment: So you only want to delete the first 3 cells in each row?

Comment: Yes, except the header

Comment: There's no need for a loop.

Comment: Can't you set the value of those cells to empty values?

Comment: There are 16 columns in the excel sheet and I would like to delete all the rows of the 1st 3 columns except the 1st row

Answer (score 0):

From what I have understand, you want to delete the first 3 cells in each row, you have to delete the column names. Or you could set them to none. I will show you both ways. Let's say the dataframe is df:

```py
df.iloc[:,[1,2,3]]=None #you can use np.nan or 0 too
```

Now if you want to drop all the 3 columns, with the names:

```py
df = df.iloc[: , 3:]
```

I hope this solves your problem!

Comment: If this worked, you can add the tick to show that the question is solved.

Comment: Where's the use of openpyxl here?

Answer (score 0):

Possibly easiest to just delete the columns and re-insert then re-add the Column Headers. Maybe an issue is the Headers formatting as this would also need to be re-applied.
The example below will do as mentioned and includes some standard font formatting so  font name, size, colour etc can be applied to the header names. Obviously change to suit or remove if no format is needed.

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl.styles import Font


del_start_col = 1
del_num_cols = 3

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('Book1.xlsx')
ws = wb['Sheet1']

col_headings = [c.value for c in next(ws.iter_rows(min_row=1, max_row=1))]

ws.delete_cols(del_start_col, del_num_cols)
ws.insert_cols(del_start_col, amount = del_num_cols)

for i in range(del_start_col, del_start_col + del_num_cols):
    ws.cell(row=1, column=i).value = col_headings[i - 1]
    ws.cell(row=1, column=i).font = Font(name='Calibri',
                                         size=12,
                                         bold=True,
                                         italic=False,
                                         vertAlign=None,
                                         underline='none',
                                         strike=False,
                                         color='000000')
wb.save(path)
```